# Performance behavior of dask.dataframe map_partitions

Tags: python, dask

```
id    ord     a1     a2     a3
--    ---     --     ---    ------
1     1       44     2.3    banana
1     3       21     2.3    banana
1     2       21     2.3    banana    <- mangle should drop this one
2     1       ...
...
```

My aim here is to, within each group (identified by indexed `id`), sorted by `ord`, drop successive "unchanged" rows. My first attempt at this was a `groupby.apply` type solution that took hours.

I pivoted to `map_partitions`, but cannot explain why this is running oddly slow. Over a single Dask partition it takes 2 seconds on a single core (~200k rows). Mapping this over a dask dataframe on a 64-core machine (some 500 partitions in total) took ~10000s!

```
def mangle(df):
    # Input dask dataframe is sorted on index, keep it that way
    df = df.sort_values(['ord']).sort_index(level=0, sort_remaining=False, kind='mergesort')
    mask = (
        df.drop(columns=['ord']).groupby(df.index).fillna(-999).shift(1) == \
        df.drop(columns=['ord']).groupby(df.index).fillna(-999).shift(0)
    ).all(axis=1)
    df = df[~mask]
    return df.groupby(df.index).fillna(method='backfill')
```

Comment: Both an example dataframe and the row I expect to drop are right there in the question?

Comment: Your `mangle` function appears to be getting rid of the third row (not the second).

Comment: Ah I see, I'll update the question. Either way, the question pertains the inexplicable (to me) performance of map_partitions.

Comment: You might try some of the techniques in the [understanding performance](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/understanding-performance.html) documentation to try to identify what is going on.